# SQL Server: Query for products with matching tags

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been pondering over this for the past few hours but I cannot find a solution.

I have a products in a table, tags in another table and a product/tag link table.
Now I want to retrieve all products which have the same tags as a certain product.

Here are the tables (simplified):

**PRODUCT**:

```
id varchar(36) (primary key)
Name varchar(50)
```

**TAG**:

```
id varchar(36) (primary key)
Name varchar(50)
```

**PRODUCTTAG**:

```
id varchar(36) (primary key)
ProductID varchar(36)
TagID varchar(36)
```

I find quite a few answers here on Stackoverflow talking about returning full and partial matches. However I am looking for a query which only gives full matches.

Example:

```
Product A has tags 1, 2, 3
Product B has tags 1, 2
Product C has tags 1, 2, 3
Product D has tags 1, 2, 3, 4
```

If I query for product A, only product C should be found - as it is the only one having exactly the same tags.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where I find it simpler to combine all the tags into a single string and compare the strings.  But, that is painful in SQL Server until 2016.

So, there is a set based solution:

```
with pt as (
      select pt.*, count(*) over (partition by productid) as cnt
      from producttag pt
     )
select pt.productid
from pt join
     pt pt2
     on pt.cnt = pt2.cnt and
        pt.productid <> pt2.productid and
        pt.tagid = pt2.tagid
where pt2.productid = @x
group by pt.productid, pt.cnt
having count(*) = pt.cnt;
```

This matches every product to your given product based on the tags.  The `having` clause then ensures that the number of matching tags is the same for the two products.  Because the `join` only considers matching tags, all the tags are the same.

Comment: I am wondering if the problem is asking for a `COUNT(DISTINCT TagID)` to make it correct (not saying your SQL is wrong - the problem statement might be ambiguous).

Comment: @LoztInSpace . . . `COUNT(DISTINCT)` would be needed if the junction table could have duplicates.

Comment: Thank you very much for this spot-on code snippet. The only thing missing is the table alias for cnt at the very end. At least in SQL Server Management Studio 2017, the query returns "ambigous column name" without the alias specified. But a "pt." in front of the cnt fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes, try this way:

```
with aa as (
    select  count(*) count
    from [PRODUCTTAG]
    where ProductID = '19A947C0-6A0F-4A6F-9675-48FBE30A877D'
), bb as
(
    select ProductID, count(*) count
    from [PRODUCTTAG]
    group by ProductID 
)
select distinct b.ProductID
from [dbo].[PRODUCTTAG] a join
    [dbo].[PRODUCTTAG] b on a.TagID = b.TagID cross join
    aa join 
    bb on aa.count = bb.count and b.ProductID = bb.ProductID
where a.ProductID = '19A947C0-6A0F-4A6F-9675-48FBE30A877D'
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! I went with @Gordons answer but I am sure yours works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @PRODUCTTAG table(id int identity(1,1),ProductID  int,TagID int)
insert into @PRODUCTTAG VALUES
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3)
,(2,1),(2,2)
,(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)
,(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4)

;With CTE as
(
select ProductID,count(*)smallCount 
FROM @PRODUCTTAG
group by ProductID
)
,CTE1 as
(
 select smallCount, count(smallCount)BigCount
 from cte
 group by smallCount
)
,CTE2 as
(
select * from cTE c
where exists(
select smallCount from cte1 c1
where BigCount>1 and c1.smallCount=c.smallCount
)
)

select * from cte2
--depending upon the output expected join this with @PRODUCTTAG,@Product,@Tag
--like this

--select * from @PRODUCTTAG PT
--where exists(
--select * from cte2 c2 where pt.productid=c2.productid
--)
```

Or Tell what is final output look like ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I went with @Gordons code as it is not as complex.

Comment: @Max, My script is written in such a manner because your output is not clear,though your requirement is clear.Secondly it will perform well under lot of data.